# How to make a settable clock stick to what is stated as the time (not to what the real time is)?

Tags: javascript

Well, I am trying to make a clock that you can change the time of, but it is not really working out the way that I would like it to.

Basically, I would like it to use what I stated in the JavaScript (`time("manualSet","12-hour","11","4","2021","16","30","0");`), so I would like the time to stay the same and count up from the time that is stated.

So, here is the code:

```js
var classPeriodDiv = document.getElementById("classPeriod");
var schoolGoDiv = document.getElementById("schoolGo");

var t = 0;
function time(type, style, month, curDay, year, hour, minute, second) {
    var tmtd=0;
    var tmtdt=0;
    function currentTime(style) {
        let date=new Date();const mh=new Array();mh[0]="1";mh[1]="2";mh[2]="3";mh[3]="4";mh[4]="5";mh[5]="6";mh[6]="7";mh[7]="8";mh[8]="9";mh[9]="10";mh[10]="11";mh[11]="12";
        let mt=new Array();mt[0]="January";mt[1]="February";mt[2]="March";mt[3]="April";mt[4]="May";mt[5]="June";mt[6]="July";mt[7]="August";mt[8]="September";mt[9]="October";mt[10]="November";mt[11]="December";
        let mn=mh[date.getMonth()];
        let mnt=mt[date.getMonth()];
        let dd=date.getDate();
        let yy=date.getFullYear();
        let hh=date.getHours();
        let hr=date.getHours();
        let mm=date.getMinutes();
        let ss=date.getSeconds();
        let session="AM";
        if(hh==0){hh=12;}
        if(style=="12-hour"){if(hh>12){hh=hh-12;session="PM";}document.getElementById("clockType").innerHTML="12 Hour";}else if(style=="24-hour"){document.getElementById("clockType").innerHTML="24 Hour";}
        mn=(mn<10)?"0"+mn:mn;
        dd=(dd<10)?"0"+dd:dd;
        hh=(hh<10)?"0"+hh:hh;
        mm=(mm<10)?"0"+mm:mm;
        ss=(ss<10)?"0"+ss:ss;
        let time1=mn+"-"+dd+"-"+yy;
        let time2=hh+":"+mm+":"+ss+" "+session;
        var day;
        if(date.getDay()==0){day="Sun";}else if(date.getDay()==1){day="Mon";}else if(date.getDay()==2){day="Tues";}else if(date.getDay()==3){day="Weds";}else if(date.getDay()==4){day="Thurs";}else if(date.getDay()==5){day="Fri";}else if(date.getDay()==6){day="Sat";}
        if(tmtd==0){document.getElementById("date").innerHTML=time1;tmtd=1;}
        if(document.getElementById("date").innerHTML!=time1){}else{document.getElementById("date").innerHTML=time1;}
        document.getElementById("tDate").innerHTML=time2;
        var colectionMinutes=(hr*60)+mm;
        document.getElementById("date").addEventListener("click",function(){if(document.getElementById("date").innerHTML==time1){document.getElementById("date").innerHTML=mnt+"-"+day+"~"+dd+"-"+yy;}else{document.getElementById("date").innerHTML=time1;}});
        
        function schoolTime() {
            if (date.getDay()==0||date.getDay()==6) {
                schoolGoDiv.innerHTML = "Today is not a School Day.";
            } else {
                schoolGoDiv.innerHTML = "Today is a School Day.";
            }
        }
        
        function currentClass(){
            colectionMinutes=(hr*60)+mm;
            if(date.getDay()==1||date.getDay()==2||date.getDay()==4||date.getDay()==5){
                if(colectionMinutes>=460){if(colectionMinutes<=512){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="1st Period";}}
                if(colectionMinutes>=512){if(colectionMinutes<=569){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="2nd Period";}}
                if(colectionMinutes>=569){if(colectionMinutes<=625){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="3rd Period";}}
                if(colectionMinutes>=625){if(colectionMinutes<=681){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="4th Period";}}
                if(colectionMinutes>=681){if(colectionMinutes>=681){if(colectionMinutes<=708){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="5th Period &#160;--&#160; 1st Lunch";}}if(colectionMinutes>=708){if(colectionMinutes<=735){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="5th Period &#160;--&#160; 2nd Lunch";}}if(colectionMinutes>=735){if(colectionMinutes<=768){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="5th Period &#160;--&#160; 3rd Lunch";}}}
                if(colectionMinutes>=768){if(colectionMinutes<=824){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="6th Period";}}
                if(colectionMinutes>=824){if(colectionMinutes<=880){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="7th Period";}}
            }else if(date.getDay()==3){
                if(colectionMinutes>=460){if(colectionMinutes<=507){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="1st Period";}}
                if(colectionMinutes>=507){if(colectionMinutes<=558){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="2nd Period";}}
                if(colectionMinutes>=558){if(colectionMinutes<=609){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="3rd Period";}}
                if(colectionMinutes>=609){if(colectionMinutes<=660){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="4th Period";}}
                if(colectionMinutes>=660){if(colectionMinutes<=694){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="Advisory";}}
                if(colectionMinutes>=694){if(colectionMinutes>=694){if(colectionMinutes<=721){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="5th Period &#160;--&#160; 1st Lunch";}}if(colectionMinutes>=721){if(colectionMinutes<=749){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="5th Period &#160;--&#160; 2nd Lunch";}}if(colectionMinutes>=749){if(colectionMinutes<=778){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="5th Period &#160;--&#160; 3rd Lunch";}}}
                if(colectionMinutes>=778){if(colectionMinutes<=829){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="6th Period";}}
                if(colectionMinutes>=829){if(colectionMinutes<=880){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="7th Period";}}
            }
            if(colectionMinutes>=880){if(colectionMinutes<=1440){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="Dissmissed";}}
            if(colectionMinutes>=0){if(colectionMinutes<=460){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="Before School - Dissmissed";}}
        }
        
        schoolTime();
        currentClass();
        //let t=setTimeout(function(){currentTime(style);schoolTime();currentClass();},1000);
    }
    
    function manualSetTime(style, month, curDay, year, hour, minute, second) {
        let date2=new Date();
        if(tmtdt==0){
            date2.setMonth(month);
            date2.setDate(curDay);
            date2.setFullYear(year);
            date2.setHours(hour);
            date2.setMinutes(minute);
            date2.setSeconds(second);
            tmtdt=1;
        }
        const mh=new Array();mh[0]="1";mh[1]="2";mh[2]="3";mh[3]="4";mh[4]="5";mh[5]="6";mh[6]="7";mh[7]="8";mh[8]="9";mh[9]="10";mh[10]="11";mh[11]="12";
        let mt=new Array();mt[0]="January";mt[1]="February";mt[2]="March";mt[3]="April";mt[4]="May";mt[5]="June";mt[6]="July";mt[7]="August";mt[8]="September";mt[9]="October";mt[10]="November";mt[11]="December";
        let mn=mh[date2.getMonth()];
        let mnt=mt[date2.getMonth()];
        let dd=date2.getDate();
        let yy=date2.getFullYear();
        let hh=date2.getHours();
        let hr=date2.getHours();
        let mm=date2.getMinutes();
        let ss=date2.getSeconds();
        let session="AM";
        if(hh==0){hh=12;}
        if(style=="12-hour"){if(hh>12){hh=hh-12;session="PM";}document.getElementById("clockType").innerHTML="12 Hour";}else if(style=="24-hour"){document.getElementById("clockType").innerHTML="24 Hour";}
        mn=(mn<10)?"0"+mn:mn;
        dd=(dd<10)?"0"+dd:dd;
        hh=(hh<10)?"0"+hh:hh;
        mm=(mm<10)?"0"+mm:mm;
        ss=(ss<10)?"0"+ss:ss;
        let time1=mn+"-"+dd+"-"+yy;
        let time2=hh+":"+mm+":"+ss+" "+session;
        var day;
        if(date2.getDay()==0){day="Sun";}else if(date2.getDay()==1){day="Mon";}else if(date2.getDay()==2){day="Tues";}else if(date2.getDay()==3){day="Weds";}else if(date2.getDay()==4){day="Thurs";}else if(date2.getDay()==5){day="Fri";}else if(date2.getDay()==6){day="Sat";}
        if(tmtd==0){document.getElementById("date").innerHTML=time1;tmtd=1;}if(document.getElementById("date").innerHTML!=time1){}else{document.getElementById("date").innerHTML=time1;}
        document.getElementById("tDate").innerHTML=time2;
        var colectionMinutes=(hr*60)+mm;
        document.getElementById("date").addEventListener("click",function(){if(document.getElementById("date").innerHTML==time1){document.getElementById("date").innerHTML=mnt+"-"+day+"~"+dd+"-"+yy;}else{document.getElementById("date").innerHTML=time1;}});
        
        //let tt=setTimeout(function(){manualSetTime(style,month,curDay,year,hour,minute,second);},1000);
    }
    
    clearInterval(t);
    if(type=="current"){
        t=setInterval(function(){
            currentTime(style);
        },1000);
    }else if(type=="manualSet"){
        t=setInterval(function(){
            manualSetTime(style,month,curDay,year,hour,minute,second);
        },1000);
    }
}
// The following is for testing only
time("manualSet","12-hour","11","4","2021","16","30","0");
```

```css
.ss {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.buttons {
    text-align: center;
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

button {
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* header */

header {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    /*padding: 3px;*/
}

/* Clock */

#time {
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    width: 500px;
}

#clockType {
    /*font-size: 16px;*/
    display: block;
}

#date {
    /*align-items: normal;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-color: rgb(0, 0, 238);
    border-style: none;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    cursor: default;
    font: inherit;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    perspective-origin: 0 0;
    text-align: start;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    width: auto;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-logical-height: 1em;
    -webkit-logical-width: auto;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 238);
    text-decoration: underline;
    background: none!important;
    border: none;
    padding: 0!important;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;*/
    display: block;
}

#tDate {
    /*font-size: 18px;*/
    display: block;
}

#schoolGo {
    /*display: block;*/
}

#classPeriod {
    /*display: block;*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="build-version" content="V00.004.00" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>HPHS Bell Schedule</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <header>
              <!-- Start Relavent Section -->
                <div id="time" class="ss">
                    <p id="clock">
                        <span id="clockType"></span>
                        <span id="date"></span>
                        <span id="tDate"></span>
                        <span>~ <span id="schoolGo"></span> -||- <span id="classPeriod"></span> ~</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
              <!-- End Relavent Section -->
                <!-- Some other content that is not important -->
            </header>
        </div>
        <!-- The following is for testing only -->
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <button onclick="time('current','12-hour')">Current (12 Hour)</button>
        <br>
        <button onclick="time('current','24-hour')">Current (24 Hour)</button>
        <!-- Some other content that is not important -->
    </body>
</html>
```

As you could see in the snippet above, when the time is set with the `manualset` type, it just doesn't stick to what I stated, so how do I fix that.

Also, you can click the `month-day-year` for more info.

Also, just ignore `schoolTime()` and `currentClass()`, as they are not all that important to the problem that I am trying to fix.

Comment: you need to clear the previous setInterval with clearInterval

Comment: "*Also, just ignore schoolTime() and currentClass(), as they are not all that important to the problem that I am trying to fix.*" Then why include them at all...? See our guidance on creating a [mre].

Comment: @esqew I included them because they have some importance to how the time function works, but does not induce the problem, so I stated to just ignore them because there is no need to change the code to those functions, but I feel the need that they should be left in.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone How would I do that with the way that I have the code set up? After all, I would need to find a way to bypass the fact that the `setIntervals` are on two different sides of the `if(){}else if(){}` statement.

Comment: put `t` in higher scope, see answer

Answer (score 0):

Put `t` in higher scope, clearInterval and use the same timer.

```js
var classPeriodDiv = document.getElementById("classPeriod");
var schoolGoDiv = document.getElementById("schoolGo");

var t = 0 // add this

function time(type, style, month, curDay, year, hour, minute, second) {
    var tmtd=0;
    var tmtdt=0;
    function currentTime(style) {
        let date=new Date();const mh=new Array();mh[0]="1";mh[1]="2";mh[2]="3";mh[3]="4";mh[4]="5";mh[5]="6";mh[6]="7";mh[7]="8";mh[8]="9";mh[9]="10";mh[10]="11";mh[11]="12";
        let mt=new Array();mt[0]="January";mt[1]="February";mt[2]="March";mt[3]="April";mt[4]="May";mt[5]="June";mt[6]="July";mt[7]="August";mt[8]="September";mt[9]="October";mt[10]="November";mt[11]="December";
        let mn=mh[date.getMonth()];
        let mnt=mt[date.getMonth()];
        let dd=date.getDate();
        let yy=date.getFullYear();
        let hh=date.getHours();
        let hr=date.getHours();
        let mm=date.getMinutes();
        let ss=date.getSeconds();
        let session="AM";
        if(hh==0){hh=12;}
        if(style=="12-hour"){if(hh>12){hh=hh-12;session="PM";}document.getElementById("clockType").innerHTML="12 Hour";}else if(style=="24-hour"){document.getElementById("clockType").innerHTML="24 Hour";}
        mn=(mn<10)?"0"+mn:mn;
        dd=(dd<10)?"0"+dd:dd;
        hh=(hh<10)?"0"+hh:hh;
        mm=(mm<10)?"0"+mm:mm;
        ss=(ss<10)?"0"+ss:ss;
        let time1=mn+"-"+dd+"-"+yy;
        let time2=hh+":"+mm+":"+ss+" "+session;
        var day;
        if(date.getDay()==0){day="Sun";}else if(date.getDay()==1){day="Mon";}else if(date.getDay()==2){day="Tues";}else if(date.getDay()==3){day="Weds";}else if(date.getDay()==4){day="Thurs";}else if(date.getDay()==5){day="Fri";}else if(date.getDay()==6){day="Sat";}
        if(tmtd==0){document.getElementById("date").innerHTML=time1;tmtd=1;}
        if(document.getElementById("date").innerHTML!=time1){}else{document.getElementById("date").innerHTML=time1;}
        document.getElementById("tDate").innerHTML=time2;
        var colectionMinutes=(hr*60)+mm;
        document.getElementById("date").addEventListener("click",function(){if(document.getElementById("date").innerHTML==time1){document.getElementById("date").innerHTML=mnt+"-"+day+"~"+dd+"-"+yy;}else{document.getElementById("date").innerHTML=time1;}});
        
        function schoolTime() {
            if (date.getDay()==0||date.getDay()==6) {
                schoolGoDiv.innerHTML = "Today is not a School Day.";
            } else {
                schoolGoDiv.innerHTML = "Today is a School Day.";
            }
        }
        
        function currentClass(){
            colectionMinutes=(hr*60)+mm;
            if(date.getDay()==1||date.getDay()==2||date.getDay()==4||date.getDay()==5){
                if(colectionMinutes>=460){if(colectionMinutes<=512){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="1st Period";}}
                if(colectionMinutes>=512){if(colectionMinutes<=569){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="2nd Period";}}
                if(colectionMinutes>=569){if(colectionMinutes<=625){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="3rd Period";}}
                if(colectionMinutes>=625){if(colectionMinutes<=681){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="4th Period";}}
                if(colectionMinutes>=681){if(colectionMinutes>=681){if(colectionMinutes<=708){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="5th Period &#160;--&#160; 1st Lunch";}}if(colectionMinutes>=708){if(colectionMinutes<=735){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="5th Period &#160;--&#160; 2nd Lunch";}}if(colectionMinutes>=735){if(colectionMinutes<=768){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="5th Period &#160;--&#160; 3rd Lunch";}}}
                if(colectionMinutes>=768){if(colectionMinutes<=824){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="6th Period";}}
                if(colectionMinutes>=824){if(colectionMinutes<=880){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="7th Period";}}
            }else if(date.getDay()==3){
                if(colectionMinutes>=460){if(colectionMinutes<=507){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="1st Period";}}
                if(colectionMinutes>=507){if(colectionMinutes<=558){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="2nd Period";}}
                if(colectionMinutes>=558){if(colectionMinutes<=609){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="3rd Period";}}
                if(colectionMinutes>=609){if(colectionMinutes<=660){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="4th Period";}}
                if(colectionMinutes>=660){if(colectionMinutes<=694){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="Advisory";}}
                if(colectionMinutes>=694){if(colectionMinutes>=694){if(colectionMinutes<=721){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="5th Period &#160;--&#160; 1st Lunch";}}if(colectionMinutes>=721){if(colectionMinutes<=749){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="5th Period &#160;--&#160; 2nd Lunch";}}if(colectionMinutes>=749){if(colectionMinutes<=778){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="5th Period &#160;--&#160; 3rd Lunch";}}}
                if(colectionMinutes>=778){if(colectionMinutes<=829){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="6th Period";}}
                if(colectionMinutes>=829){if(colectionMinutes<=880){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="7th Period";}}
            }
            if(colectionMinutes>=880){if(colectionMinutes<=1440){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="Dissmissed";}}
            if(colectionMinutes>=0){if(colectionMinutes<=460){classPeriodDiv.innerHTML="Before School - Dissmissed";}}
        }
        
        schoolTime();
        currentClass();
        //let t=setTimeout(function(){currentTime(style);schoolTime();currentClass();},1000);
    }
    
    function manualSetTime(style, month, curDay, year, hour, minute, second) {
        let date2=new Date();
        if(tmtdt==0){
            date2.setMonth(month);
            date2.setDate(curDay);
            date2.setFullYear(year);
            date2.setHours(hour);
            date2.setMinutes(minute);
            date2.setSeconds(second);
            tmtdt=1;
        }
        const mh=new Array();mh[0]="1";mh[1]="2";mh[2]="3";mh[3]="4";mh[4]="5";mh[5]="6";mh[6]="7";mh[7]="8";mh[8]="9";mh[9]="10";mh[10]="11";mh[11]="12";
        let mt=new Array();mt[0]="January";mt[1]="February";mt[2]="March";mt[3]="April";mt[4]="May";mt[5]="June";mt[6]="July";mt[7]="August";mt[8]="September";mt[9]="October";mt[10]="November";mt[11]="December";
        let mn=mh[date2.getMonth()];
        let mnt=mt[date2.getMonth()];
        let dd=date2.getDate();
        let yy=date2.getFullYear();
        let hh=date2.getHours();
        let hr=date2.getHours();
        let mm=date2.getMinutes();
        let ss=date2.getSeconds();
        let session="AM";
        if(hh==0){hh=12;}
        if(style=="12-hour"){if(hh>12){hh=hh-12;session="PM";}document.getElementById("clockType").innerHTML="12 Hour";}else if(style=="24-hour"){document.getElementById("clockType").innerHTML="24 Hour";}
        mn=(mn<10)?"0"+mn:mn;
        dd=(dd<10)?"0"+dd:dd;
        hh=(hh<10)?"0"+hh:hh;
        mm=(mm<10)?"0"+mm:mm;
        ss=(ss<10)?"0"+ss:ss;
        let time1=mn+"-"+dd+"-"+yy;
        let time2=hh+":"+mm+":"+ss+" "+session;
        var day;
        if(date2.getDay()==0){day="Sun";}else if(date2.getDay()==1){day="Mon";}else if(date2.getDay()==2){day="Tues";}else if(date2.getDay()==3){day="Weds";}else if(date2.getDay()==4){day="Thurs";}else if(date2.getDay()==5){day="Fri";}else if(date2.getDay()==6){day="Sat";}
        if(tmtd==0){document.getElementById("date").innerHTML=time1;tmtd=1;}if(document.getElementById("date").innerHTML!=time1){}else{document.getElementById("date").innerHTML=time1;}
        document.getElementById("tDate").innerHTML=time2;
        var colectionMinutes=(hr*60)+mm;
        document.getElementById("date").addEventListener("click",function(){if(document.getElementById("date").innerHTML==time1){document.getElementById("date").innerHTML=mnt+"-"+day+"~"+dd+"-"+yy;}else{document.getElementById("date").innerHTML=time1;}});
        
        //let tt=setTimeout(function(){manualSetTime(style,month,curDay,year,hour,minute,second);},1000);
    }
    
    // then change to this, note t is the same timer
    clearInterval(t)
    if(type=="current"){
        t=setInterval(function(){
            currentTime(style);
        },1000);
    }else if(type=="manualSet"){
        t=setInterval(function(){
            manualSetTime(style,month,curDay,year,hour,minute,second);
        },1000);
    }
}
// The following is for testing only
time("manualSet","12-hour","11","4","2021","16","30","0");
```

```css
.ss {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.buttons {
    text-align: center;
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

button {
    cursor: pointer;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
}

/* header */

header {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    /*padding: 3px;*/
}

#h1Border {
    border: 2px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 36px;
    left: 440px;
    width: 480px;
    height: 50px;
}

/* Clock */

#time {
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    width: 500px;
}

#clockType {
    /*font-size: 16px;*/
    display: block;
}

#date {
    /*align-items: normal;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-color: rgb(0, 0, 238);
    border-style: none;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    cursor: default;
    font: inherit;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    perspective-origin: 0 0;
    text-align: start;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    width: auto;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-logical-height: 1em;
    -webkit-logical-width: auto;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 238);
    text-decoration: underline;
    background: none!important;
    border: none;
    padding: 0!important;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;*/
    display: block;
}

#tDate {
    /*font-size: 18px;*/
    display: block;
}

#schoolGo {
    /*display: block;*/
}

#classPeriod {
    /*display: block;*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="build-version" content="V00.004.00" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>HPHS Bell Schedule</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <header>
              <!-- Start Relavent Section -->
                <div id="time" class="ss">
                    <p id="clock">
                        <span id="clockType"></span>
                        <span id="date"></span>
                        <span id="tDate"></span>
                        <span>~ <span id="schoolGo"></span> -||- <span id="classPeriod"></span> ~</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
              <!-- End Relavent Section -->
                <!-- Some other content that is not important -->
            </header>
        </div>
        <!-- The following is for testing only -->
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <p>Note: The glitch that makes the thing that states the clock hour format swap back and forth, is only present with the click of the buttons.</p>
        <button onclick="time('current','12-hour')">Current (12 Hour)</button>
        <br>
        <button onclick="time('current','24-hour')">Current (24 Hour)</button>
        <!-- Some other content that is not important -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This still doesn't make it work the way that I'd like it to. Basically, I would like it to use what I stated in the js (`time("manualSet","12-hour","11","4","2021","16","30","0");`), so I would like the time to stay the same and count up from the time that is stated.

Comment: it has fixed the issue *The glitch that makes the thing that states the clock hour format swap back and forth, is only present with the click of the buttons / As you could see in the snippet above, when the time is set with the manualset type, it just doesn't stick to what I stated, so how do I fix that*, you cant throw additional requirements in to move the goal post, ask another question. If you ask multiple questions its not allowed and will be closed as needs more focus.

Comment: Well, it is one question, I had asked how to fix it so that it would stick, and the part that I  stated about the glitch was just a note so that I knew it was happening, and anyway on the site this code is on, the buttons for changing the time from a 12-hour clock to a 24-hour clock was not going to be in place yet, so you answer a question that I did not ask. So, I probably should have stated that the glitch was not the problem, after all, I only use that part to test the code.